# Execute terminal commands from AppleScript in a single window

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript

I want to execute some terminal commands from my AppleScript. I am executing this with in a for loop. The problem is, for each loop I am getting a new window in Terminal. But I want to execute my all commands in a single window. How I can I do this?

My code is like this,

```
repeat with i from 1 to 5

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        set currentTab to do script "date"
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
set currentTab to do script "date" in window 1
```